# SQL Server - Error in MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

EDITED: I put the table structure and the real MERGE

I'm trying to use a MERGE in Microsoft SQLServer 2014 but I'm getting a syntax error in the Target table:

```
MERGE VALORATION_DETAIL_INPUTS_LIMIT AS Target
USING (VALUES (922, 4098)) AS Source(idValoration, idDetValInput)
ON (Source.idValoration = Target.idValoration AND Source.idDetValInput = Target.idDetValInput)
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET idSubject = 1633, idGood = 1114, idWarranty = 7519, idSubWarranty = 7520, units = 1.000000,
               unitPrice = 250.000000, limit = 250.000000, percTax = 21.000000, tax = 52.500000, subtotal = 197.500000,
               total = 250.000000 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (idDetValInput, idValoration, idSubject, idGood, idWarranty, idSubWarranty, units,
            unitPrice, limit, percTax, tax, subtotal, total) 
    VALUES(4093, 922, 1633, 1114, 7519, 7520, 1.000000, 250.000000, 250.000000, 21.000000, 52.500000, 197.500000, 250.000000)
OUTPUT $ACTION
```

The error is:

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line ...`
`Incorrect syntax near the word 'AS'.`

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE VALORATION_DETAIL_INPUTS_LIMIT
(
    idDetValInput bigint NOT NULL,
    idValoration bigint NOT NULL,
    idSubject bigint NOT NULL,
    idGood int NULL,
    idWarranty int NULL,
    idSubWarranty int NULL,
    units real NULL,
    unitPrice money NULL,
    limit money NULL,
    percTax real NULL,
    tax money NULL,
    subtotal money NULL,
    total money NULL
)
```

Comment: You have no "Line 14" in the query.

Comment: Well, I have a "USE" and a "GO" before. I didn't think it was necesary to put it.

Comment: Now, your problem is different.  "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement." So,what i did is to add two values at the end in VALUES part of INSERT statement and it works fine. In short, 13 columns specified in INSERT statement are more than 11 VALUES provided in VALUES part of INSERT statement. There are 2 more values that need to be provided there.

Comment: Fixed that, still getting the same error (never got the one you say, thou).

Comment: Then, that error is not in MERGE, I ran your table script + your merge script on a new database in a new window and it works fine after I add values to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I asked my manager about the problem and he told me that the version of SQL Server doesn't support MERGE. So... my bad. Sorry for the wasted time :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Use values clause instead of creating Source table through SELECT, or you can also use option suggested by user @m.benslimane.
2. Also, since you are updating Target, you need not use Target.id, Target.value in INSERT statement.
3. This is most probably POC code, since you are updating with static values. Do take care of this in real query.

   ```
   MERGE VALORATION_DETAIL_INPUTS_LIMIT AS Target

    USING (VALUES (922, 4098)) AS Source(idValoration, idDetValInput)

    ON (Source.idValoration = Target.idValoration 
    AND Source.idDetValInput = Target.idDetValInput)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  

   UPDATE SET idSubject = 1633, idGood = 1114, idWarranty = 7519, 
      idSubWarranty = 7520, units = 1.000000,
      unitPrice = 250.000000, limit = 250.000000, 
      percTax = 21.000000, tax = 52.500000, subtotal = 197.500000,
      total = 250.000000 
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

   INSERT (idDetValInput, idValoration, idSubject, idGood, 
           idWarranty, idSubWarranty, units,unitPrice, 
           limit, percTax, tax, subtotal, total) 

   VALUES(1633, 1114, 7519, 7520, 1.000000, 
          250.000000, 250.000000, 21.000000, 
          52.500000, 197.500000, 250.000000, 
          --DUMMY VALUES I ADDED  BELOW
          20.00, 20.00)

   OUTPUT $ACTION;
   ```

Comment: I fixed those things, thanks for the tips. But I'm still getting the same error. It looks like SQL Server doesn't like MERGE, :(

Comment: @AndrésMarotta I created a table and ran the query I pasted here after I saw it working fine. Can you paste your table structure in the query also?

Comment: Also, which version of SQL server you are on?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQLServer 2014. I'll update the question with the table structure.

Comment: does it think in the following;
USING (VALUES (922, 4098)) AS Source(idValoration, idDetValInput)
they are a different type i.e. not bigint?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add (id,value) after as source.

like this :

```
.... Target
USING (SELECT 922 AS id, 4098 AS value) AS Source (id,value)
ON ........
```